# Getting a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in DataTables when exporting to Excel or CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
$('#example2').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
         {
            extend: 'excel',
            messageTop: range
        }
    ]
 });
```

WWhen I generate a report containing more than 20,000 records, and then click on the Excel button, it shows an error 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLoxs.png)

Comment: I am not able to recreate your problem using the code in your question (replacing `range` with `'foo'`, since I don't know how `range` is defined). 20,000 rows are exported correctly (albeit very slowly). Chances are you have a problem in how `range` is defined - but that is a guess. Try removing `messageTop: range`, just as a test.